# How can I use Python Variables with the UPDATE command in MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I have been trying to make this part of my A-Level project where I have a database in MyPHPAdmin and my code grabs a value, compares it to a preset value and if it is unchanged, uses that location in the database to store a new value. *(I cant just insert new data due to other parts of my code)*. I have been trying to use a variable with a value stored in it from an input box, however it refuses to take the value. I have tried lots of things and I cant seem to get it to work and I seem to get a different error everytime I try something different. I fear it may just be something simple I am missing, but for the life of me I cant figure it out and it is driving me insane. *(Also yes I have looked at the documentation but it is not of much use for my situation)*

My Code:

```
mycursor = database.cursor(buffered=True)
mycursor.execute("SELECT name FROM creationPokemon")
myresult = mycursor.fetchone()[0]
print(myresult)

if myresult == "Placeholder1":
    sql = ("UPDATE creationPokemon SET name = %s WHERE name = %s")
    val = ('Placeholder1', cName)
else:
    myresult = mycursor.fetchone()[0]
    print(myresult)

mycursor.execute(sql)
database.commit()
```

The error I have landed on this time is:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s WHERE name = %s' at line 1
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python and mysql connector need at least 2 dimemsns when you use tuples and you need to fill both placeholders

```
mycursor = database.cursor(buffered=True)
mycursor.execute("SELECT name FROM creationPokemon")
myresult = mycursor.fetchone()[0]
print(myresult)

if myresult == "Placeholder1":
    sql = "UPDATE creationPokemon SET name = %s WHERE name = %s"
    val = (cName,cName)

    mycursor.execute(sql,val)
    database.commit()
else:
    myresult = mycursor.fetchone()[0]
    print(myresult)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding but this still shows up the same error.

Comment: i changed soem lines, as they make more sense in this regard, i still don't know where Cname comes from. Also your update Query woul only make sense if you select only one pokemon or you want to replace all placeholders so you need a loop

Comment: thanks alot, i managed to get it working using this, saved me a massive headache <3